# How to make hardcoded text BOLDED in SSRS page header?

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

I have page header in my SSRS report. Using Visual Studio 2010.
In a text box I have this expression:

="Date From : " & Parameters!DateFrom.Value & Environment.NewLine()  & "Date To: " & Parameters!DateTo.Value & Environment.NewLine()

But how can I make hardcoded `"Date From : "` and `"Date To: "` looks BOLD? Or different color?

[image]

My expression:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create two placeholders, one for `Date To` and other for `Date From`.

Right click the inside of your textbox and select `Create Placeholder`:

[image]

Use `="Date To"` and bold the text using the menu bar icon.

[image][image]

Then add another placeholder for the rest of the expression.

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you for awesome explanation.